# Where do the function names in clojure.core.async derive from and could they use descriptive ones?

Tags: clojure, core.async

I've recently started to use the `core.async` library and I'm a bit puzzled why it uses function names like these:

- `>!`
- `>!!`
- `chan`

I always have to think about the number of exclamation marks for example when I'm not sure which is the *parking* version and which is the *blocking* one. This reminds me of the book "Don't make me think" and the book "Clojure Programming" where this is written:

> Clojure's syntax reduces the cognitive load necessary to read or write code ... Every time a programmer has to pause and think about this (or look it up in a manual) ... a mental page fault has occured.

What is the explanation for this?

Comment: Should we replace `*` with `multiply`, and `cons` with `prepend-single-item`?

Comment: @amalloy - Is PC creeping into the one last "safe zone" I have left!?!?!?

Comment: I'm editing the question title to make it less likely to be closed. It sounds like this is a bit frusterating and nobody likes to have their questions put on hold. Sorry about that. Could you edit the body to make it easier to tell what a good answer would look like?

Comment: It seems like a reasonable question to me, not sure why all the down votes. I like them personally I think the short hand is well chosen and appropriate. Choosing names is something important that we should discuss more. They are cryptic, and they are appropriate.

Comment: @TimothyPratley the title was more provocative when the down-votes where cast. I think it was provoking people. Hopefully they will come back and remove them.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt I downvoted and voted to close because, to me, the original title and body indicated a nonconstructive question whose answers would be primarily opinion-based. The updated title you gave the question would make it far more constructive, but since you asked the OP in your comment to edit his question to clarify his intent, I was waiting for him to make that edit before retracting my votes. If you and Timothy think that the question, as it currently stands, is useful and constructive, I would be happy to retract my votes.

Comment: I too am waiting for him to come back and edit. Let's wait and see.

Comment: @amalloy your metaphor is limping since everybody who attended school knows that `*` is for multiplication and everybody who knows lisp knows that `cons` is for construct. This does not stand for `>!` which is not used elsewhere and *is not* a mathematical notation.

Comment: Sorry I was sleeping (I'm in Europe).

Comment: Sorry for the provocative question it was not my intention.

Comment: @AdamArold I disagree that amalloy's metaphor is "limping". It's essentially the same point that Rich Hickey makes in his [Simple Made Easy](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy) talk. Whether or not one already knows a certain notation is a completely subjective measure. Clojure was the first Lisp I learned, so the name `cons` was not already familiar to me. I had to *become* familiar with it while learning the language. In the same way, to learn to use `core.async` effectively, you must *become* familiar with the names `>!`, `>!!`, `chan`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I speculate that when using core.async you will be writing `go` `parking-put` `blocking-take` `create-channel` many times, hence it was deemed suitable to have a shorthand. `>` and `<` as put and take are fairly obvious because of the directionality. Perhaps the `!` means the side-effect of getting the value onto a channel, and `!!` means the side-effect of getting onto the channel and creating a thread. In any case the meaning should be read as one bang means state machine, two bangs means threads.

Notation and shorthand allows more concise code, and if one adopts core.async the use of those operators tends to quickly permeate the code... so it seems to be a good tradeoff in this case, despite the obvious downsides to search-ability and self-evidence.

Zach Tellman has thoughtful comments on naming in his talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaKLSH4csqE and book https://leanpub.com/elementsofclojure

Comment: `bang means state machine, two bangs means threads`
This is maybe the most insightful part of your answer.

Answer (score 3):

A tiny mnemonic: think of `>` respectively `<` as a funnel that acts like an endpoint of your `chan`nel. `!` (or `!!`) is the message you'd like to put into (`>!`) or take from (`<!`) that channel.

[image]

Unfortunately, I can give you no explanation why `!` stands for parking and `!!` for blocking, but I think you get used to it real quick. Furthermore, it lets you write concise code that doesn't distract from the actual business logic.

**EDIT:** After watching [Timothy Baldridge's talk on core.async from Clojure/conj 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enwIIGzhahw), I'd like to add this quote (skip to [6:15](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enwIIGzhahw&feature=youtu.be&t=6m15s)):

> […] the first exclamation mark kind of means that it's not transaction-safe […] and the second one just signifies that this is a blocking operation.

Comment: That is an awesome graphic. Did you make it?

Comment: @AdamArold: Thanks, I did it as part of a presentation about Clojure at my alma mater.

Answer (score 1):

I share your pain.  I always have to stop and think in order to translate a name like `<!` into the "parking version of take that only works in a go loop".  I've started working on some more human-friendly names (still a work in progress!):

```
(ns tupelo.async
  "tupelo - Making Clojure even sweeter"
  (:require [clojure.core                 :as clj]
            [clojure.core.async           :as clj.async] )
  (:gen-class))

; #todo add tests
; #todo add docs to README

(defmacro put-go! [& args]
  `(clj.async/>! ~@args))

(defmacro take-go! [& args]
  `(clj.async/<! ~@args))

(defn put-now! [& args]
  (apply clj.async/>!! args))

(defn take-now! [& args]
  (apply clj.async/<!! args))

(defn put-later! [& args]
  (apply clj.async/put! args))

(defn take-later! [& args]
  (apply clj.async/take! args))
```

https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/src/tupelo/async.cljc